# Starting an application with coded UI tests in VS 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, coded-ui-tests

When I recorded a test with the recorder in Visual Studio 2010 Premium, I noticed that the recorder doesn't generate the code to start the program.

Steps to repro:

1. Add a new Coded UI test to a VB .NET testing project
2. Click "OK" to use "Record actions, edit UI map or add assertions"
3. Click the record button to start recording.
4. Press CTRL+F5 in Visual Studio to start your program
5. Click the "Generate Code" button.
6. Observe that no code is generated as far as running things go.

Considering that starting a program is a rather important part of testing a program, I'm sure there's a solution for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your UIMap.vb file:

**(Be certain to change the EXE to match your own)**

```
Namespace RouteManagement_UI_Tests
   Partial Public Class UIMap
      Public Sub StartApp()
         Dim RMS As ApplicationUnderTest = ApplicationUnderTest.Launch(Me.StartAppParams.ExePath, Me.StartAppParams.AlternateExePath)
      End Sub

      Public Overridable ReadOnly Property StartAppParams() As StartAppParams
         Get
            If (Me.mStartAppParams Is Nothing) Then
               Me.mStartAppParams = New StartAppParams()
            End If
            Return Me.mStartAppParams
         End Get
      End Property

      Private mStartAppParams As StartAppParams

   End Class

   Public Class StartAppParams
#Region "Fields"
      '''<summary>
      '''</summary>
      Public ExePath As String = "C:\Somebinary.exe"

      '''<summary>
      '''</summary>
      Public AlternateExePath As String = "%VisualStudioDir%\Somebinary.exe"
#End Region
   End Class
End Namespace
```

Then refer to this method in your test code as follows:

```
Public Class CodedUITest1
   <TestMethod()>
   Public Sub Test1()
      With Me.UIMap
         .StartApp()
     .ExitApp()
      End With
   End Sub
End Class
```